# Example of open and bounded subset of $\Bbb R$ that is not totally bounded

Tags: metric-spaces, examples-counterexamples

An interval $(a,b)$ is totally bounded in $\Bbb R$.

Would $\bigcup\limits _{n\ge1}(1/2^n,1/{2^{n-1}})$ or $\bigcup\limits _{n\ge1}(1/\alpha^n,1/{\alpha^{n-1}})$ for $\alpha\in\Bbb R_{>2}$ be good examples?

Comment: Related are [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/332733/euclidean-bounded-metric-space-implies-total-boundedness) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/722331/is-there-any-difference-between-bounded-and-totally-bounded).

Answer (score 2):

Actually, in $\mathbb{R}^n$, *every* bounded set (open or not) is a subset of some compact set, and therefore it is totally bounded.

Comment: So what is wrong with my examples? They're totally bounded aren't they?

Comment: My original answer was just plain silly. Please read the edited version.

Comment: In $\mathbb R^n$ you do not need to say anything about compact.  It is easy to show every bounded set in $\mathbb R^n$  is totally bounded.

Comment: @JohnCataldo: your examples are bounded and totally bounded, so they do not answer the question in the title.

Comment: So being inside a compact set in $\Bbb R^n$ makes you totally bounded? Is it true in general?

Comment: Yes. It holds on any metric space.